# Bulk E-mails verify in MailGun

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailgun, email-validation

I am trying to send bulk e-mails via **MailGun SDK** in my app, If at least one e-mail is not satisfying MailGun email validation, then i am getting failed error, and not sending mail to other valid emails too.

So is there any way that i can check all the emails valid or not sending. How MailGun is verifying all domain e-mails . Please let me know if any one have idea about it. Appreciate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailgun is not providing API to validate bulk of email together. You can use this below code for validating single email id :

```
curl -G --user 'api:pubkey-5ogiflzbnjrljiky49qxsiozqef5jxp7' -G \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/validate \
    --data-urlencode address='foo@mailgun.net'
```

Below will be the response for above query :

```
{
    "address": "foo@mailgun.net",
    "did_you_mean": null,
    "is_disposable_address": false,
    "is_role_address": true,
    "is_valid": true,
    "parts": {
        "display_name": null,
        "domain": "mailgun.net",
        "local_part": "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kalpesh Panchasara. I can validate my mail by using this URL.